# A older man and woman living under the same roof

Tags: catholicism

What is the position of the Catholic Church regarding an unmarried post menopausal woman living under the same roof (maintaining separate bedrooms) as an unmarried permanently impotent man? Are they living in sin if there is absolutely no form of intimacy whatsoever? (The man has mild autism and cannot abide any form of intimacy, either physical, not even an accidental touch of a shoulder in passing, or psychological. The woman is his care taker. There is no one else living in the home.)

Comment: If this question is about a particular man and woman, I would suggest talking to your local priest about it rather than asking about it here. This site isn't meant to give pastoral advice about specific personal situations.

Comment: I believe this is answerable from Catholic doctrine.  I don't think it is necessary to have all the caveats in here. Basically, can any man and woman live together permanently without causing scandal?

Comment: As Peter said, this is a question about Catholic doctrine. My experience over many years is that every priest has  totally differing opinions about many of the questions asked on this site. Their interpretation of Catholic doctrine is through their personal point of view.  Some are very liberal. Others are supremely rigid. Their ideas vary widely. What I want to know is what official Catholic doctrine is, not the opinion of a local parish priest.

Comment: It becomes a pastoral advice question as soon as it moves from the general ("What is the RCC doctrine on...?) to the particular -a specified person and a specified situation.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, the Catholic Church would reserve judgement or position on this because it is not in the context of Marriage or Sexual relationships.
There are vast situations where people need in-home care by caregivers of the opposite sex.

If there is possibility of scandal or abuse, then there should be steps taken to mitigate these and put some "checks and balances" & transparency.

Comment: That is good to know. Yes, there are vast situations indeed where older women provide 24/7 in-home care for older men.